# pdo array getting Array to string conversion error

Tags: php, pdo, prepared-statement

When I run this code it should store `ben` in the database but, it says `Array` in the `first_name` column and it gives the string to conversion error. How would I get rid of the error?

```
<?php $data = ['first_name' => 'ben'] ?>
<?php $sql = "INSERT INTO names (first_name) values (?);" ?>

<?php $statement = $pdo->prepare($sql); ?>
<?php $statement->execute([$data]); ?>
```

Comment: `$data` is already an array, don't wrap it in `[]` in the call to `execute()`.

Comment: You also don't have to wrap every line in `<?php ?>`, you can have as many lines as you want between the begin and end tags.

Answer (score 2):

PDO has two different ways to bind parameters. The first is positional. In this case, the array you pass to `execute()` should be an *indexed* array, with values in the same order that you want them to bind to the question marks:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO table (col1, col2) values (?, ?)";
$data = ['value for col1', 'value for col2'];
```

Note the values *must* be in the same order that they're going to be used:

```
$data = ['value for col2', 'value for col1']; // This won't work, wrong order!
```

The alternative (and in my opinion, superior) method is to use named parameters. Here, you need to use an *associative* array with a key named the same as your parameter placeholder.

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO table (col1, col2) values (:col1, :col2)";
$data = ['col1' => 'value for col1', 'col2' => 'value for col2'];
```

The order of these now does not matter because they're keyed by the array name instead of the position:

```
$data = ['col2' => 'value for col2', 'col1' => 'value for col1']; // Still good!
```

Your problem (in addition to the extra array wrap that @Sammitch pointed out) is that you have mixed these two techniques together in an incompatible way -- you're using positional parameters, but have provided an associative array. So, in your case, you either need to use positional parameters and an indexed array:

```
$data = ['ben'];
$sql = "INSERT INTO names (first_name) values (?);";
$statement = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$statement->execute($data);
```

Or named parameters and an associative array:

```
$data = ['first_name' => 'ben'];
$sql = "INSERT INTO names (first_name) values (:first_name);";
$statement = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$statement->execute($data);
```